# getting build dependencies and source by default

Tags: compiling, downloads, dependencies

Is there an application by which the build dependency as well as the source code of the software gets downloaded automatically as soon as we install the software from a .deb package or the software center?

Answer (score 6):

To install the build dependencies for `foo`, run

`apt-get build-dep foo`

To get the source code, run

`apt-get source --download-only foo`

Note that this downloads three files into the current directory: a tarball of the source code, a compressed `.diff.gz` patch file, and a `.dsc` metadata file. Omit the `--download-only` option to have the command unpack the source code for you too.

If you'd like this to happen automatically, you could write a wrapper script that automatically calls each of `apt-get install`, `apt-get build-dep`, and `apt-get source`.

If you installing directly from `.deb` files instead of accessing an APT repository, then you might not be able to do this, because `.deb` files do not contain source code, or even a link to the source code they were built from.

There is some more information on the [apt-get man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).