# "sensors/sensors.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: software-installation, cpu

I download the latest stable version of psensor: psensor-1.0.4. I try to install it from source on Ubuntu 12.04. `./configure` generates a Makefile, But when I run `make`,

```
psensor.h:22:29: fatal error: sensors/sensors.h: No such file or directory
```

I searched and found that it was with `lm_sensors-devel` which I haven't installed. But I can't find `lm_sensors-devel` to install. any solution? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting build dependencies and source by default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/212027/getting-build-dependencies-and-source-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing `libsensors4-dev`, which appears to be the package that contains `sensors/sensors.h` on my 12.04 box

```
$ dpkg -L libsensors4-dev | grep '\.h$'
/usr/include/sensors/error.h
/usr/include/sensors/sensors.h
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how to find out that I need to install `libsensors4-dev`? Are `lm_sensors-devel` and `libsensors4-dev`  the same thing?

Comment: @Tim you may find the `apt-file` utility useful for this kind of thing

Comment: as you might know, the -dev packages have the headers, or *.h files. If the documentation does not tell you, you sometimes have to google search to identify the needed packages. You can try http://askubuntu.com/questions/212027/getting-build-dependencies-and-source-by-default

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I don't understand. I now install from source which I downloaded from its website and cannot be found in the repository of apt. The link you gave is for installation from the  apt repository. Am I right?

Comment: Uses apt to install the dependicies

Answer (score 1):

To know the libraries needed to compile psensor, see:
http://wpitchoune.net/gitweb/?p=psensor.git;a=blob;f=README;h=3b50a77ce265e5763cb4eb2ea94ff80727e99e93;hb=HEAD

For lmsensor dependency, you have to install libsensors4-dev:

> sudo apt-get install libsensors4-dev

lm_sensors-devel package does not exist on ubuntu, this package name sounds like the name of the Fedora/Redhat package name...

Instead of compiling/installing last version of psensor yourself, you may want to consider using the ppa:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install psensor